# The value of attribute [ data-type ] must be in double quotes - custom html widget error

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use a JavaScript typewriter effect and WordPress is throwing me the following error (The value of attribute [ data-type ] must be in double quotes.) when adding the html into a custom html widget.

I have the code working on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/swiftcreative/pen/pLywRO). However w hen I change the data-type to double quotes and the data inside to single quotes the code stops working.

Any suggestions/am I missing something?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Single quotes (') are not allowed in JSON

Comment: Do you have any tips on how I could tweak my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change it to CSV

```
data-type="Information Gathering, Farming & Husbandry, Delivery Service, Emergency Response, Remote Inspections, Mapping & Surveying, Maritime Success, Military & Defense Support, Scientific Research, Real Time Surveillance "
```

then do

```
var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-type').split(", ");
```

the `.split(", ")` turns the CSV string into an array. then do

```
new TxtType(elements[i], toRotate, period);
```

the `toRotate` is passed into `TxtType` as-is, it's not parsed by JSON anymore, just kept the array it is.

*prepare for a mod to flag this as unrelated to wp*